# Problemas con las tildes en el asunto de PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Estoy usando PHPMailer para enviar correos electrónicos de recuperación de contraseña, bienvenida...etc. El caso es que el cuerpo del mensaje está correctamente codificado aplicando `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';` pero el asunto del mensaje no reconoce las tildes, por ello me llegan sin asunto.

Aquí pego el código:

```
require("../phpmail/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Mailer="smtp";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "XXXXX"; 
$FromServ = "XXXXX";
$mail->Username = "XXXXX"; 
$mail->Password = "XXXXX"; 
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->From = "XXXXX";; 
$mail->Timeout=60;
$mail->Sender = "XXXXX";;
$mail->FromName = "XXXXX"; 
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$subject = "Recuperar contraseña";   // << No reconoce la Ñ 
$mail->Subject = $subject; 
$body= '  AQUÍ EL MENSAJE';  
`
```

Si alguien sabe como puedo hacer para codificar correctamente el asunto me haría un gran favor. Ya he aplicado reglas como `utf8_decode ()` y lo único que hace es cambiar la Ñ por un signo de interrogación (Recuperar contrase?a).

Gracias a todos de antemano.

Answer (score 10):

Normalmente esto se resuelve haciendole un decode al contenido antes de establecer el `Subject` del objeto mail:

```
$subject = "Recuperar contraseña";
$subject = utf8_decode($subject);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
```

Y después establecer el juego de caracteres (`Charset`) del objeto mail:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Comment: Este me funcionó, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4):

A mi lo que me ha funcionado es lo siguiente:

```
$subject = "Recuperar contraseña";
$subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."=?=";
$mail->Subject = $subject;
```

Comment: He probado todas las respuestas de este hilo, y la que me terminó resultando fue la siguiente: $subject = "Recuperar contraseña"; $subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."=?="; $mail->Subject = $subject; *Envidada por user173508

Answer (score 4):

Tenía el mismo problema y quedó solucionado al colocar el charset() despues del isHTML, no fue necesario usan el encode o decode

```
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Answer (score 1):

Únicamente debes editar el archivo PHPMailer.php donde se define la clase.

y en la línea 77 donde se define el charset debe quedar asi:

```
public $CharSet = self::CHARSET_UTF8;
```

Comment: mala practica alterar las librerias de terceros... no somos eternos si alguien actualiza las librerias con composer tendran problemas si se pierde el script editado...

Answer (score 1):

A mi lo que me funcionó fue esto:

```
$subject = "Recuperar contraseña";
$subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."=?=";
$mail->Subject = $subject;
```

lo utilicé con phpmailer y me fue de maravilla.
el fragmento lo adapte de un comentario que le agradezco a @user173508